# Javascript blocking multible scripts with mutation observer doese't work

Tags: javascript, html, mutation-observers

i've created a script that block script defined in a json array.

But when i load more then 2 scripts the blocking doesen't work anymore.

Can anyone tell me what my mistake is or give me a hint how i can make it work with multible scripts.

This is blocking the google recaptcha script:

```
    <script>
        function blockScript(origin) {
            const scripts = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("SCRIPT"));
            if (scripts.length > 0) {
                scripts.forEach((script) => {
                    if (script.src.includes(origin)) {
                        document.head.removeChild(script);
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    </script>
    <script>

      var json = [
{
    "name" : "Google Recaptcha", 
    "url"   : "www.google.com",
    "desc" : "Recaptcha",
    "rights": ""
}];
            const observer = new MutationObserver((mutationsList, observer) => {
                for(let mutation of mutationsList) {
                    const addedNodes = Array.from(mutation.addedNodes);
                    if (addedNodes && addedNodes.some(n => n.nodeName === 'SCRIPT')) {
                      for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        var obj = json[i];

        console.log(obj.url);
        blockScript(obj.url);
    }
                    }
                    observer.disconnect();
                }
            });
            observer.observe(document, { childList: true, subtree: true });
    </script>
        <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=MYKEY"></script>
```

---

And this isn`t.

```
    <script>
        function blockScript(origin) {
            const scripts = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("SCRIPT"));
            if (scripts.length > 0) {
                scripts.forEach((script) => {
                    if (script.src.includes(origin)) {
                        document.head.removeChild(script);
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    </script>
    <script>

      var json = [
{
    "name" : "Google Recaptcha", 
    "url"   : "www.google.com",
    "desc" : "Recaptcha",
    "rights": ""
}];
            const observer = new MutationObserver((mutationsList, observer) => {
                for(let mutation of mutationsList) {
                    const addedNodes = Array.from(mutation.addedNodes);
                    if (addedNodes && addedNodes.some(n => n.nodeName === 'SCRIPT')) {
                      for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        var obj = json[i];

        console.log(obj.url);
        blockScript(obj.url);
    }
                    }
                    observer.disconnect();
                }
            });
            observer.observe(document, { childList: true, subtree: true });
    </script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=MYKEY"></script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I’m on my phone so I can’t test thoroughly but it looks like your observer disconnects inside the loop, so after the first mutation, it disconnects.

Comment: Try moving the observer.disconnect() outside of the for (let mutation loop.

Comment: @BenjaminJamesKippax thanks for your hint! but it doesen't work it's still only blocking the first script... :/

Comment: out of interest do you need to disconnect it at all? If you remove the disconnect all together, that would also account for lazy loaded scripts too, would it not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the disconnect method will fix this and account for lazy loaded scripts, too.

Comment: @lvollmer Prego.